# Returning multiple file pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, pipe

I'm new to C and would like some help with an issue I have. I'm reading and writing to pipes as follows:

```
f = fdopen(fdH2P[WRITE], "w"); // writing to pipe, returns a file pointer
```

and

```
r = fdopen(fdP2H[READ], "r"); // reading from pipe
```

I want to return both these file pointers from my function. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Wrap them into a structure and return that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either put the two file pointers into a structure and return that, or you can pass pointers to the function, like this

```
void GetPipes( FILE **wptr, FILE **rptr )
{
   *wptr = fdopen(fdH2P[WRITE], "w");
   *rptr = fdopen(fdP2H[READ], "r");
}

void SomeOtherFunction( void )
{
   FILE *wptr, *rptr;
   GetPipes( &wptr, &rptr );
   ...
}
```

Comment: I tried the pointers method and I seem to have gotten it right I think because the compiler's not throwing any warnings, but now when I try to read from the pipe like so 'fprintf(stdout, "%c\n", fgetc(rptr));', it doesn't work. It works fine when I only return 1 file pointer from my function so my piping is correct, but it breaks when I try to return both file pointers, following your example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AliKhokhar -- I suggest that you `printf("w=%p r=%p\n",*wptr,*rptr);` in `GetPipes` and `printf("w=%p r=%p\n",wptr,rptr);` in the other function. The results should be identical if you've got everything right.

Comment: I do get identical values: 

w=0x1588250 r=0x1588250
w=0x1588250 r=0x1588250

But nothing is going through my pipes. I tried to log the contents as they pass through and the log files are empty. Totally stumped.

Comment: @AliKhokhar -- Seems odd that the `wptr` and the `rptr` are the same. Are those pointers the same in the working code that returns only 1 file pointer from your function?

Comment: I think your suggestion is working fine, the problem lies somewhere in my piping. I've selected your answer as the solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can return a struct:

Define struct, with typedef for convenience

```
typedef struct dual_fp {
    FILE *read_fp;
    FILE *write_fp;
} dual_fp;
```

Add function to open two files

```
dual_fp dual_fdopen(int write_fd, int read_fd) {
    dual_fp ret;

    // review error handling and reporting,
    // such as add error code fields to struct dual_fp,
    // and possibly do not open 2nd / close 1st file if the other fails

    ret.write_fp = fdopen(write_fd, "w");
    if (!ret.write_fp) perror("dual_fdopen for write");

    ret.read_fp = fdopen(read_fd, "r");
    if (!ret.read_fp) perror("dual_fdopen for read");

    return ret;
}
```

Call it

```
dual_fp fps = dual_fdopen(fdH2P[WRITE], fdopen(fdP2H[READ]);
// use fps.read_fp and fps.write_fp after checking they are not NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `struct` and return an instance of the `struct`.

```
typedef struct
{
    FILE* write;
    FILE* read;
} FilePointers;


FilePointers foo()
{
   // Assuming you have access to the data...

   FILE* w = fdopen(fdH2P[WRITE], "w");
   FILE* r = fdopen(fdP2H[READ], "r");

   FilePointers fp = {w, r};
   return fp;
}
```